# Can't set border attributes to AntTable row based on value of record

Tags: reactjs, antd

I need to set conditional border attributes to some of my rows in AntTable(React). I can change some other attributes like background-color, width, height through `rowClassName`, but somehow border styles doesn't work.

```
.isFirst {
   border-color: #5d3ebc;
   border-top: 1px;
   background-color: aqua;
}
.isLast {
   border-bottom: 40px;
   border-color:  #5d3ebc;
   height: 100px;
}




return (
    <AntTable
      rowClassName={(record, index) => (record.batchInfos.isFirstIndex ? 'isFirst' : 'isLast')}
      data={activeOrders}
      columns={columns}
      loading={isPending && showLoadingSpinner}
      pagination={pagination}
      onPaginationChange={handlePaginationChange}
    />
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide `border-collapse` to the table first

```
.ant-table table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Now define `border-width` and `border-style` along with `border-color` properties in css.

```
.isLast {
  ...
  border-bottom-width: 7px;
  border-color: #5d3ebc;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

Comment: It totally worked man. I can't express how grateful I'm to you :)